# How to access 802.1x network with non-802.11x device

Tags: wifi, access-point

I want to use my nexus 5x to make presentations, but apparently, there is no video support. I tried an asus miracast dongle, but that is spotty at best. So it appears that my only good option is to use a chromecast device, but my university uses the 802.1x protocol, which chromecast apparently does not support.

Is there a way to use a travel router to do what I want? I see two options:

1. The router does not connect to the internet and simply allows my phone and the chromecast to communicate. I don't know if chromecast needs internet access to work.
2. It connects to the internet using the 802.1x protocol, but then provides a different protocol (11n, etc) for my phone and the chromecast.

Will either of these options work? Or some other setup? Specific hardware suggestions are of course welcome.

Comment: You must have an active Internet connection to use a Chromecast. A travel router can be used to get around the AP isolation that most hotels enforce but you must have an Internet connection. is from this link: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chromecast/XRktmNTk0QY